# A way to combine the numbers from 1 to 9 and get a number in which any two consecutive digits e divisible by 7 or 13.

Tags: number-theory

Find a way to write the digits from 1 to 9 in sequence, in such way that the numbers determined by any two consecutive digits is divisible by 7 or 13. 
This is let $a_{1}=1,...,a_{9}=9$ find a way to write 
$$a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{9}}$$ such that $a_{i}a_{i+1}$ is divisible by 7 or 13 for $i=1,...,8$.

(Here we mean $a_{i_{1}}a_{i_{2}}\cdots a_{i_{9}}=10^{8}a_{1}+10^{7}a_{2}+\cdots+10a_{8}+a_{9}$, as well $a_{i}a_{i+1}=10a_{i}+a_{i+1}$.)

This problem is from OBM (Brazilian Mathematics Olympiad)

Comment: What is the meaning of *in sequence*?

Comment: One after the other, as is written in the problem $a_{i_{1}}...a_{i_{9}}$

Comment: What will come *one after the other*?If the numbers $1,2,3,....,9$ come one after the other what is the meaning of the problem?

Comment: No, you have to form a number with this nine numbers, as for example 123456789 or 987654321

Comment: ok....order of numbers does not matter,I assume....

Comment: I find $a_{i}a_{i+1}$ ambiguous, as well as the statement "*the numbers determined by any two consecutive digits*". How exactly are they determined? Do you mean $a_{i}\cdot a_{i+1}$ or $10a_{i}+a_{i+1}$?

Comment: the number determined by $10a_{i}+a_{i+1}$, thank you @Mirko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiples of $13$ with two digits are $13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 91$.

Multiples of $7$ with two digits, without $0$ or repeated digits, are $14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 84, 91$. It has to start with $7$, because noone ends with $7$. Hence

$$
784913526.
$$

Edit, beated in time ..

Answer (score 2):

784913526
Hint: write down all the numbers with 2 digits divisible by 7 and/or 13 (delete 70 and 77), then draw an oriented graph with 9 points and try to find a good path.